# strtotime fails for valid date

Tags: php

i am doing a project where i need to output date of orders. and i do the following inside a for loop

```
<?php echo date('M d, Y g:i A',strtotime($order['Order']['created']));?>
```

for some strange reason, sttotime returns false. (**Dec 31, 1969 7:00 PM** appears instead.)

i made sure $order['Order']['created'] is not empty and is valid.

even stranger, that exact same piece of code works fine on the other page, only different is that, that one is not in a loop. but that cant be the reason right?

i set timezone to **America/New_York** and $order['Order']['created'] is **mysql timestamp**.

var_dump on said variable

```
string(27) "2010-06-16 20:12:51"
```

oh. $%#$ me. i was [sanitizing](http://book.cakephp.org/view/464/clean) output. it must have messed up the dashes and colons.

Comment: Add the result of `var_dump($order['Order']['created'])` to your question

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem here.

Comment: As others have said .. [cannot reproduce](http://codepad.org/dDjVF7p3) ..

Comment: please close it then or answer yourself as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Converting Funky Dude's edit to an answer to get it from the unanswered list:

---

oh. $%#$ me. **i was sanitizing output**. it must have messed up the dashes and colons.